# Double pointers in stack implementation of linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, stack

I was reading a book recently and this is the explanation for implementing stack in Linked list. Here follows the explanation:

```
typedef struct Element { 
    struct Element *next; 
    void *data;
} Element;
```

The corresponding prototypes for push and pop follow:

```
void push( Element *stack, void *data );
void *pop( Element *stack );
```

Now consider what happens in these routines in terms of proper functionality and error handling. 
Both operations change the first element of the list. The calling routine’s stack pointer must be modified to reflect this change, but any change you make to the pointer that is passed to these functions won’t be propagated back to the calling routine. You can solve this problem by having both routines take a pointer to a pointer to the stack. This way, you can change the calling routine’s pointer so that it continues to point at the first element of the list. Implementing this change results in the following:

```
void push( Element **stack, void *data );
void *pop( Element **stack );
```

However, what I wonder is, what is the need to put double pointers for the stack? I understand the concept of double pointers, but however, when a new node is created using 
`Element *node1 = (Element *) malloc (sizeof(Element));`, we already have the pointer to the node. Why not just send this pointer itself instead of using double pointer?

Comment: You were so successful in explaining why a "double" pointer is required, that it is unclear what you are really wondering about. The key argument seems to be " The calling routine’s stack pointer must be modified to reflect this change".

Comment: You can read it as: any change you make to the pointer that is passed to these functions would be propagated back to the calling routine

Comment: Then I guess I don't completely understand "calling routine's stack pointer". Can someone explain?

Comment: all parameters in C are passed by value.  So if you want to change a value of a variable in another function, you have to pass in the address of that variable.  The calling routine is where you call "push" or "pop" from.  The stack pointer is your stack variable -- that's a pointer and it's (likely) on the stack.

Comment: @user1652263 if the caller of a function passed an `int` parameter, and you wanted to possibly modify the `int` variable passed by the caller, what do you have to do? Declare the formal parameter to be a pointer-to-int, and pass the *address* of the variable in the caller to the function being called. Passing a pointer-variable by address is no different. If you may possibly modify the pointer, then you need to pass *it* by address as well; declare the formal parameter to be a pointer to (pointer-to-node) and pass the *address* of the pointer from the calling function. Its the same mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have a standalone Stack object, every time you change the top node in the stack, the primary reference to that stack needs to change for everything using it.  This is why the double pointer is needed -- because the old top of the stack isn't valid anymore.

If you created a top-level stack object, which has a pointer to an Element and maybe some other data like a element count, then you would be able to send that in to push/pop as a single pointer because that object/struct would remain the same, only the data inside it would change.

```
// pseudocode
struct Stack {
  Element * top = NULL;
  int size = 0;
}

struct Element {
  Element * next;
  void * data;
}

function push(Stack * stack, void * data) {
  Element * element = new Element(data);
  element->next = stack->top;
  stack->top = element;
  size++;
}

// pop left as an exercise to the reader.. :)

int main(void*) {
    Stack * stack = new Stack;
    push(stack, "foo"); <== no need for double pointer
    pop(stack); 
    printf("%d\n", stack->size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit confusing due to a common mix-up of concepts of `pointers` and `passing by reference`.

Let's take look at the original `push` function. The `stack` parameter represents a pointer to the beginning of the stack. This pointer is provided by the caller. If the beginning of the stack needs to be modified, the `push` function won't be able to do this because **it was passed by value**, i.e., inside function body it's a copy of the original. Same goes for `pop`.

It's easiest to  understand with an example. Let's say the beginning of the stack resides at address `0x1234`. When `push` is being called, the **value** `0x1234` is passed to it by the caller. `push` can do whatever it desires with this value, but it won't change the data of the original pointer and the changes won't be reflected at the caller context.

Why not send the `node1` pointer that you've created inside `push`: `Element *node1 = (Element *) malloc (sizeof(Element));` ? That's exactly what you should do but you still need double pointer:

```
void push( Element **stack, void *data )
{
    Element *node1 = (Element *) malloc (sizeof(Element));
    node1->data = data;
    node1->next = *stack;
    *stack = node1;
}
```

If you attempt to achieve this without double pointer, the caller won't see the changes and will remain with an old stack pointer:

```
void push( Element *stack, void *data )
{
    Element *node1 = (Element *) malloc (sizeof(Element));
    node1->data = data;
    node1->next = stack;
    stack = node1;         //The data structure was updated but caller won't see it!
}
```

Comment: and on a pop, you'll crash your program, because you freed up the memory (or at least should have)

Comment: @xaxxon Exactly how did you get to this conclusion? Of course, all of the above doesn't remove the need to check for NULLs and handle them graciously.

Comment: sorry, i meant in his example, as you said, when you push it would be lost.  And in his example if you did a pop, the caller would still have a pointer to freed memory and the next time it was used, segfault.

Comment: @xaxxon ah, got you - you're talking about the bad example. Yes, that's true

Comment: is it possible to implement reveres of this ? linked list using stack? reverse of usual data structure topics?